# Beginner Java trouble with Parameters

Tags: java, parameters, return

I am currently learning Java, and have been having problems with parameters. I'm trying to create a program that takes age as input, and classifies the person based on said age.

- Younger than 2 is a baby
- Younger than 4 is a toddler
- Younger than 13 is a child
- Younger than 20 is a teenager
- Younger than 35 is a young adult
- Younger than 65 is middle aged
- Younger than 100 is geriatric
- 100 and older is antique

It needs to return a string classifying the person. I wrote this:

```
String getMaturityLevel(int age) {

    if (age < 2)
       return ("a baby");
    if (age < 4)
        return ("a toddler");
    if (age < 13)
        return ("a child");
    if (age < 20)
        return ("a teenager");
    if (age < 35)
        return ("a young adult");
    if (age < 65)
        return ("middle aged");
    if (age < 100)
        return ("geriatric");
    if (age >= 100)
        return ("antique");
}
```

Which doesn't compile as it needs a return statement.

So my problem is, how do I effectively write the code?  I don't know how to store the results. I tried something different with `age < 2`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when none of the conditions are true?

Comment: Try this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html you first need to learn if-else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm old school, so I believe in only one entry and exit point for a method or function...

The essence of your problem comes down to the compilers inability to guarantee that any one `if` statement "may" be meet (you and I know that the last one should be, but the compiler won't take that risk).

So instead of having a `return` for every condition, you could define a single `return` variable and change it's value based on your needs, for example...

```
String getMaturityLevel(int age) {
    String maturity = "antique";
    if(age < 2)
        maturity = ("a baby");
    else if(age < 4)
        maturity = ("a toddler");
    else if(age < 13)
        maturity = ("a child");
    else if(age < 20)
        maturity = ("a teenager");
    else if(age < 35)
        maturity = ("a young adult");
    else if(age < 65)
        maturity = ("middle aged");
    else if(age < 100)
        maturity = ("geriatric");

    return maturity; 
}
```

Now, in this small piece of code, it may not make much difference, but when you deal with methods that are longer or have multiple compound if/loop statements, a single `return` statement anywhere in the code can ruin your understanding of what you think the method is doing...it's a nit pick, but anything that makes my life easier ;)

I would also encourage you to use `{...}` around your `if` statements, it will stop you from doing something like...

```
else if(age < 100)
    maturity = ("geriatric");
    maturity = "Why is the returned value for every condition?";
```

Comment: Thankyou I was trying to lean towards one return statement at the end but was unsure how to do it, also we are told not to use {} unless its going to be a block. ie more than one command executed at a time. But in future I'll take it on board as we want code to be easily understandable.

Comment: The problem with not using `{...}` around your `if` blocks is that it's really easy to miss putting a extra line of execution where you expect it to be run for only the condition you want, but end up finding it gets executed every time...nasty debugging fun ;) - Also, as someone who has being in the industry some 14+ years, I'd say `if(something){ singleLine }` is more then acceptable ;)

Comment: Seconded, `if something {do_work;}` is acceptable, readable and your compile won't care. But `if something do_work; do_more_work;` will crash. The best practice is to be more robust than efficient.

Answer (score 1):

At the end where

```
if(age >= 100)
return("antique");
```

write

```
else
return("antique");
```

This is because the compiler thinks there's a possibility there is no return statement if they are all if's(imagine a scenario where everything is false).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Misread the question.

It appears you strictly have only `if` statements (no `else if` statements) therefore at the end of your last `if` statement, you need to add a `return` statement:

```
    String getMaturityLevel(int age) {

if(age < 2)
    maturity = ("a baby");
if(age < 4)
    return("a toddler");
if(age < 13)
    return("a child");
if(age < 20)
    return("a teenager");
if(age < 35)
    return("a young adult");
if(age < 65)
    return("middle aged");
if(age < 100)
    return("geriatric");
if(age >= 100)
    return("antique");
return "no maturity level found";
}
```

It will only return "no maturity level found" if none of the previous `if` conditions are `true`.

Comment: Beat me by that much... oh wait, you edited! :P Still yours came up first.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an **Enum** type (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) that would enumerate your maturity levels. Each maturity would have a "value" that would be your string. You could then iterate over your Enum elements and make a single line or two of code... if each element also has a "maturityAge".

```
public enum MaturityEnum {
  BABY (2, "A baby"),
  // etc
  private int maturityAge;
  private String maturityMsg ;

  // Accessors etc
}

public int getMaturityLevel(int age) {
  for (MaturityEnum maturity : MaturityEnum.getValues()) {
    if (maturity.getMaturityAge() > age) 
       return maturity.getMaturityMsg() ;
       // only works if the values of MaturityEnum are in the good order
       // to ensure this, you could make a function that gives the list of MaturityEnums
       // in the good order :)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, even better, is end it with a `return "Error"` at the very end without removing anything. This "Error" should never, ever happen, but if it does, you know something went wrong. It's a little bit more robust, I think, and allows you to make the qualification for "antique" (>100) clear still without having to read a single other option.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely change all of the if statements after the first to else if. Also I would recommend putting brackets around each else if / if statement.